# How do I make redisearch docker image persist data?

Tags: docker, redisearch

I'm using redislabs redisearch docker image locally for working with redisearch, but I would like the created indexes and documents still be there after restarting the redisearch container. I tried volume mapping - it didn't work. What did you do to make it persist?

Comment: Please include the full details of how you ran the container with mapping - it should work afaik.

Comment: @Itamar Haber i'm pulling the image and running it with: docker run -p 6379:6379 -v /home/user/Documents/data:/data redislabs/redisearch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have not set the persistence configuration directives, so no data is persisted.

You can either provide a configuration file, or provide them as command line arguments. For example, the following activates RDB snapshot per the defaults:

```
$ docker run -p 6379:6379 -v /tmp/data:/data redislabs/redisearch --loadmodule /usr/lib/redis/modules/redisearch.so --save 3600 1 300 100 60 10000
```

Regardless, you can verify that the mount has succeeded and manually save the RDB with a call to [`BGSAVE`](https://redis.io/commands/bgsave). You should be able to see the 'dump.rdb' at your host.

Comment: thanks @Itamar Haber, that did it. but, what does this do: --save 3600 1 300 100 60 10000 ?

Comment: This configures automatic snapshotting with the default values - you can read the description for the `save` directive in the redis.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from volume mapping you have to start with persistent storage enabled ( --appendonly yes ). View https://hub.docker.com/_/redis

docker run -d --net=host -v redisearch:/data redislabs/redisearch:latest --loadmodule /usr/lib/redis/modules/redisearch.so --appendonly yes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with setting `config` on `Redisearch`. I solved this through `env`:

`docker run  -p 6379:6379 -e REDISEARCH_ARGS="TIMEOUT 5000" redis/redis-stack:latest`

It set `Timeout` to `5000ms`.